# Does Dask take advantage by the use of parquet partition for groupby task?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dask

I want to know if dask can perform a clever groupby task?

As example we have the parquet dataset:

- `category=foo/data.pq`
- `category=bar/data.pq`

those parquet file have following columns: `name,age,other`

I would like to know for a group by `['category', 'name', 'age']` if dask would take advantage of the parquet partition `category`?

According to my understanding pandas would try to perform a comparison on all rows. While in such case, it could use the parquet partition in order to do only a group by `['name', 'age']` on each partition to save time and memory.

Thanks

Best regards